# Fragment disappears on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have a viewpager that hosts a fragment that in turn host two nested fragments. They are initialized just fine but when i rotate the screen the last of the nested fragments disappears (Page2Fragment). When I rotate back again it's there.

I think it might be related to this issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52112

But that issue is said to be fixed but it doesn't work for me. My question is if anyone has a workaround for this? I post the code I use below:

ViewPagerActivity:

```
package com.example.swekjaks.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


public class ViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
     * and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.task_pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
            // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, select the previous step.
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new MainContainerFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }
    }

}
```

MainContainerFragment:

```
package com.example.swekjaks.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainContainerFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_container, container, false);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        AddFirstFragment(fragmentManager);
        AddNextFragment(fragmentManager);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void AddFirstFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        Page1Fragment fragment = (Page1Fragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout_fragment1);

        if (fragment == null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Page1Fragment page1Fragment = new Page1Fragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayout_fragment1, page1Fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout_fragment1, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }

    private void AddNextFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        Page2Fragment fragment = (Page2Fragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout_fragment2);

        if (fragment == null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Page2Fragment page2Fragment = new Page2Fragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayout_fragment2, page2Fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout_fragment2, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

View for FragmentMainContainer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout_fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout_fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Page1Fragment:

```
package com.example.swekjaks.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Page1Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_page_1, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Page2Fragment:

```
package com.example.swekjaks.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Page2Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_page_2, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this finally by adding the following piece of code:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        //Remove fragments:
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        Page1Fragment fragment1 = (Page1Fragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout_fragment1);
        Page2Fragment fragment2 = (Page2Fragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout_fragment2);

        if (fragment1 != null){
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment1);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        if (fragment2 != null){
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment2);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


    }
```

So, I detach the fragments and instead of calling fragmentTransaction.replace(...) I call

```
fragmentTransaction.attach(fragment);
```

This seems to work and so far I haven't seen any drawbacks